# Can't create GeoServer data store from RDS PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to add a PostGIS data store to my Geoserver but it is returning the below error:

```
Error creating data store, check the parameters. Error message: Unable to obtain connection: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The connection attempt failed.)
```

I've read other posts with the same or similar problem but none of them seem to be using AWS. For me, the PostGIS connection is from AWS RDS, and the Geoserver is running on AWS EC2. I have my inbound rules set where the EC2 handles all traffic from within the security group that includes the RDS database, so theoretically they should be able to talk to each other. I've checked and verified all my parameters are correct so that's not the issue. I've also looked at the developer logs, but there isn't any useful information about why the data store creation failed. I'm guessing it has to do with the security rules but I don't know what more I can do.

Comment: Can you connect to the RDS from the command line with psql?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out my EC2 and RDS were in separate VPC groups due to different regions. I created a new EC2 instance in the same region as RDS which fixed the connection issue.